# How to display image and receive user input in the same block of code for Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to display different image based on the different user input received. Why aren't the image displayed?

**What I expecting / trying to do:**

When input is sad:

[image: When input is sad]

When input is happy:

[image: When input is happy]

**What I actually get:**

[image]

**My code:**

```
from IPython import display
    
while True:
    i = input()
    if i == "Sad":
        display.Image("Sad.png")
    elif i == "Happy":
        display.Image("Happy.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

To display the image using `IPython.display.Image`, you need to use the `display()` function.

```
from IPython.display import Image, display

while True:
    i = input("Choose an image: ")
    if i == "Sad":
        display(Image("Sad.png"))
    elif i == "Happy":
        display(Image(filename="Happy.png"))
    elif i == "quit":
        break
```